# Simulate higher-kinded types in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have an interface defined like this in Kotlin (1.8):

```kotlin
sealed interface MyInterface<T>
```

I have two implementations:

```
object Impl1 : MyInterface<String>
object Impl2 : MyInterface<Int>
```

Now, I want to create a class (`MyClass`) with one method (`myMethod`), that takes *any* type that has one generic parameter and returns a result of this type. For example:

```kotlin
val myClass = MyClass<MyInterface>() // I'd like to make sure that the type passed to MyClass has exactly one generic parameter of any type
val result1 = myClass.myMethod(Impl1) // "result" would be of type String
val result2 = myClass.myMethod(Impl2) // "result" would be of type Int
```

If `myMethod` is called with something that is *not* an instance of `MyInterface` then I want to get a compile-time error. Note however, that `MyInterface` is just an example of a type with one generic parameter, but I don't want to be limited to this type. It should be possible to modify the example above to e.g. take a `Comparable` instead.

You can achieve this in languages that support higher-kinded types, but this is not available in Kotlin. But I'm looking for a workaround if such a thing exists?

Comment: The starting point for this would be https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/pull/87, please look through the discussion thread. Kotlin now has an experimental feature of contextual receivers which can somewhat simulate requiring an implementation of a type class and providing it.

Comment: Interesting! But I fail to understand how it would help me (but I might not fully understand context receivers yet). Could you perhaps provide an answer with an example?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer below. I'm not sure it is exactly the right way to simulate typeclasses with contextual receivers, but that should be a good start if you want to dig into the feature.

Comment: UPD: I can see that it does not directly answer your question about parameterized types. I'll try to figure out how you can adapt it to parameterized types, too.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do this using the contextual receivers (they are experimental as of Kotlin 1.8.20 and require a flag to be enabled, see below).

In any place where you either have a `context(Monoid<Foo>)` or an implicit receiver of the type `Monoid<Foo>` (such as the one introduced by `with(...) { ... }`), you will be able to call `combine` on a `Foo` instance as well as call `empty` returning a `Foo`.

What's important is that you will also be able to use the extension `combineAll` on the list of `Foo`s in the context of a `Monoid<Foo>`.

The current state of the language feature requires you to carry the "type instance" around in a more or less explicit form, providing an implementation of the functions that a type class has for the particular type.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    with(IntMultiplyMonoid) {
        println(combineAll(listOf()))
        println(combineAll(listOf(1, 2, 3)))
    }
    with(StringConcatMonoid) {
        println(combineAll(listOf()))
        println(combineAll(listOf("a", "b", "c")))
    }
}

context(Monoid<M>)
fun <M> combineAll(items: Iterable<M>): M {
    return items.fold(empty()) { acc, it -> acc.combine(it) }
}

interface Monoid<M> {
    fun empty(): M
    fun M.combine(other: M): M
}

object StringConcatMonoid : Monoid<String> {
    override fun empty(): String = ""
    override fun String.combine(other: String): String = this + other
}

object IntMultiplyMonoid : Monoid<Int> {
    override fun empty(): Int = 1
    override fun Int.combine(other: Int): Int = this * other
}
```

---

In Kotlin 1.8.20, you can enable the contextual receivers feature in Gradle projects with this snippet:

```kotlin
kotlin.sourceSets.all { 
    languageSettings.enableLanguageFeature("ContextReceivers")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand how I can use this to solve my problem. I want "myMethod" to be a part of a library, but users of this library should be able to define _any_ interface/class they like, as long as it takes one generic parameter. I don't see how this would help, since if my library defines "context", I don't know about "Monoid" (or any other interface) since this type would be defined by the user.